# Unable to retrieve key value from object using ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Currently learning express but having trouble getting a value, and I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated

I'm unable to get key values which are provided to the view through an object from a JSON file.

I can display 1 key value `totalPrice`
but I'm unable to retrieve the products id or qty value.

I've tried a number of things and during debugging mode on vs code I can see `cart.products` in my controller does resolve to being an array with 2 objects.

I can display `<%= cart %>` with outputs `[object Object], [object Object]`

cart.json

```
{  
   "products":[  
      {  
         "id":"7275",
         "qty":2
      },
      {  
         "id":"5697",
         "qty":2
      }
   ],
   "totalPrice":159.96
}
```

cart.js (controller)

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
    Cart.fetchAll((cart) => {
        res.render('shop/cart', {
            pageTitle: 'Cart',
            path: '/cart',
            cart: cart.products,
            totalPrice: cart.totalPrice
    });  
    })
}
```

(view)
rendering using ejs engine, to get `totalPrice` works OK

```
<p>Total price: <b>£<%= totalPrice %></p></b>
```

but for some reason I can't get `id` or `qty` even though 2 divs are output. so it's picking up that there are 2 products in the cart but not able to retrieve the key value for id or qty

```
<% for (let product in cart) { %>
<div>
   <%= product.id %>
   <%= product.qty %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cart` is an array of objects, not an object itself.
Try this:

```
<% cart.forEach(function(product) { %>
<div>
   <%= product.id %>
   <%= product.qty %>
</div>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: I did the same. In my case array coming in data field. So whenever I run, I will get data is not defined error..

Comment: @JaynaTanawala Can you ask this in a question?  I need to see an example of your code to help.

Comment: here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61918890/5433067