# Not able to display value from array of objects in express node js with EJS template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to display data which is coming from database. In controller file I am getting array of objects and I am passing that array of objects to my ejs file. On my ejs file I am getting that "nameOfArray" is not defined.

Here is my controller file:

```
product.find().lean().exec((err, products) => {
  if(err) {
     return;
   }
   else {
      let productsList = products;
      res.render('admin/products', { data: productsList });
   }
})
```

Here is product.ejs file:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
       <% data.forEach(function(product) { %>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%= product.productName %>
            </td>
          </tr>
     <% }); %>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

By running this it is showing that **data is not defined.**

Comment: Did you set the view engine to ejs in your `controller.js` file?